# How Change Audio Input Device in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, input, preferences

I have an application that works with Chrome, it needs to constantly change the default audio input of chrome, but what I noticed is that the *Preferences* file, TAG has the **"default_audio_capture_device"**,
 but this Device ID encrypted or something the type. 
I wonder if there is any way to change the entry *Preferences*, or even if there is a way for me to get that encryption can only change the string in the file.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?